# Как восстановить GRUB?

Tags: linux, windows, grub, boot, dual-boot

Стоял Linux Mint и Windows 7.
Слетела винда.
Переустановил  Windows и затерся grub.  Можно ли без переустановки восстановить загрузочный сектор для linux ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Нужно загрузиться с *LiveCD*, далее смонтировать корневой раздел установленной Linux системы, например, в папку `/mnt`.

Станем суперпользователем

```bash
$ sudo su
```

Узнаем какие Linux увидел разделы и файловые системы

```bash
# fdisk -l /dev/sda
# blkid
# lsblk
```

Монтирование корня

```bash
# mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
```

Где `sda3` - раздел с корневой файловой системой установленного Linux.

Если содержимое /boot было расположено в отдельном от корневой файловой системы разделе, его тоже необходимо монтировать. Но в начале конечно всегда монтируется корень, после уже файловая система с `boot` в `/mnt/boot` Необходимо, если после монтирования корня каталог /boot установленной системы пуст.

Пример монтирования /boot.

```bash
# mount /dev/sda4  /mnt/boot/
```

Потом выполнить монтирование *виртуальных ФС*

```bash
# mount --bind /dev  /mnt/dev
# mount --bind /dev/pts  /mnt/dev/pts
# mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
# mount --bind /dev  /mnt/dev
# mount --bind /sys  /mnt/sys
```

Сменим текущий корень

```bash
# chroot /mnt
```

Вы окажетесь уже в вашей старой системе, после этого выполнить

```bash
# grub-install
# update-grub2
```

Выйдем из корня установленной системы

```bash
# exit
```

Первая команда установит загрузчик `stage1 grub2` в MBR, вторая обновит список загрузки - выполнит поиск систем и добавит их в меню загрузки.

Далее необходимо размонтировать все файловые системы в обратном порядке

```bash
# umount /mnt/sys
# umount /mnt/dev
# umount /mnt/proc
# umount /mnt/dev/pts
# umount /mnt/dev
# umount /mnt/
```

Далее выключите компьютер. Включите. Установите загрузку с жесткого диска.

```bash
# reboot
```

Comment: а зачем монтировать 2 раза "mount --bind /dev  /mnt/dev"

Answer (score 8):

Это самый безопасный метод востановления GRUB. Для него не нужно chroot-окружение, даже не нужны блочные устройства из `/dev`.

*Пояснение:*

*GRUB определяет жесткие диски, подсоединеные к интерфейсам SATA и IDE, как `(hdномер устройства)`; нумерация начинается с нуля. Раздел определяется следующим номером после номера устройства.*

*Примеры:*

- `(hd0)` — 1-й жесткий диск целиком;
- `(hd0,0)` — 1-й раздел на 1-ом диске;
- `(hd0,1)` — 2-й раздел на 1-ом диске;
- и так далее.

GRUB2 начинает нумеровать раздела с 1, а устройства по прежнему с нуля.*

*Внимание: GRUB позволяет получить эту и другую функциональность ещё до загрузки OS. Во избежания взлома надо установить глобальный пароль. Для получения дальнейших подробностей смотрите документацию к загрузчику.*

Порядок действий:

1. Грузим GNU/Linux с CD или USB.
2. Запускаем от root-а GRUB в режиме shell-оболочки:

   ```
   # grub
   ```
3. Далее определяем как определено устойство grub-ом, для этого вводим следующую команду:

   - если `/boot` — отдельная ФС: `# find /grub/stage1`;
   - если нет: `find /boot/grub/stage1`.
     GRUB в ответ выведит раздел на котором этот файл. Он та и нужен для следующих манипуляций.
4. Сказать GRUB'у где boot-раздел/каталог

   ```
   # root (номер_нужного_диска,номер_нужного_раздела)
   ```

   Пример:

   ```
   # root (hd0,0)
   ```
5. Указать устройство для записи в MBR первого сектора:

   ```
   # setup (нужный_раздел)
   ```

   Пример:

   ```
   # setup (hd0)
   ```
6. Всё сделано. GRUB настроил MBR на загрузку себя с нужного вам раздела. Выходим из GRUB:

   ```
   # quit
   ```