# Windows не видно в Grub 2

Tags: windows, ubuntu, grub, dual-boot

У меня на компьютере стоял Windows, я поставил fedora 15 и в Grub 2 перестал отображаться Windows. Что делать, как его вернуть в меню выбора?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Как восстановить GRUB?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/9842/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-grub)

Comment: @ReinRaus: Не ясно, что это вопрос-дубликат. Там ситуация: установка Винды затирает загрузку уже установленной Linux (ожидаемо). Здесь старая Винда не была подхвачена во время установки новой Linux (не должно происходить -- не ясно помогут ли ответы из первого вопроса ). Не говоря о том, что fedora и mint являются разными дистрибутивами.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в /boot/grub/list.cfg. может выбор Windows попросту закомментирован? Иногда и такое случается... На "крайняк" можно и вручную дописать.

Answer (score 1):

ну первым делом команду update-grub

---

торым читать и делать по анаолгии с http://lifecity.com.ua/blog/view/608 второй способ.мне в свое время весьма помог.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать для востановления "Super Grub Disk". Думаю проблемы с поиском и мануалами в сети проблем возникнуть не должно.

[Сайт программы](http://www.supergrubdisk.org).

Answer (score 0):

У меня была подобная ситуация послу установки Ubuntu, на форумах все советуют менять конфиг GRUB, но мне например помогла команда апдейта граба :

```
sudo update-grub
```

Сразу после выполнения в терминал вывалилось несколько строк, среди которых была "Обнаружен загрузочный файл Windows /каталог/".

Даже если не поможет, хуже от выполнения данной команды точно не станет =)