# Как переустановить/перезаписать путь к grub?

Tags: linux, grub, kali-linux, mbr, gpt

Ситуация: я установил Kali на флешку (установка прошла неудачно), и вместе с Kali перезаписался grub на флешку. Теперь компьютер запускается только с флешкой :)
Вопрос, нужно переустановить grub, или перезаписать путь к нему?
С 1 понятно, мануалов много. А с перезаписью будет сложнее.

Вот такие ошибки выдает:
1 фото - при попытке загрузки новой ОС.
2 фото - при попытке загрузки без флешки.

[image: При запуске kali с флешки]

[image: А вот что происходит, если флешка не вставлена]

Comment: Зачем такие велосипеды? Тут проще заново переустановить

Comment: Не понимаю это рвение многих работать с Kali. Ведь не самый простой инструмент, а большинство плюх можно на любой ОС на ядре linux прилепить. Все дело в сериалах и YouTube, они людям голову морочат

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/9842/262779

Comment: [Вот мануалы Kali на русском](https://docs.kali.org/pdf/kali-book-ru.pdf), может поможет разобраться лучше с системой.

Comment: @L.F.C. да ладно, тут и понимать нечего — это же «специальный дистрибутив для проведения тестов на безопасность», а ведь все неофиты хотят почувствовать себя кулхацкерами...

Comment: @Fat-Zer я то это понимаю :)))

Comment: Желчь мозги выела? Никому в голову я пришло. что я УЧИЛСЯ ИБ, а не явлюсь спецом ИБ. Потому что спец не использует kali как основной дист.

p.s. Спасибо за ссылки.