# Загрузочная утилита Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, администрирование

У меня на диске было установлено две ос: винда и ubnutu(они соответственно на разных разделах). То есть при загрузке компьютера я мог выбрать какую ос загружать. Мне потребовалось переустановить винду, после чего выбор исчез, автоматически стала загружаться только винда. Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно сделать, чтобы вернуть как было. Можно ли как-то переустановить эту утилиту или придётся переустанавливать ubuntu?

---

Мне помогло только https://losst.ru/vosstanovlenie-grub2#%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2_Boot_Repair

Конечно,не идеально (в grub добавился ещё один не нужный вариант), но теперь могу войти и в винду и линукс.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/9842

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как восстановить GRUB?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/9842/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-grub)

Comment: Ну, по этим инструкциям я добился того, что теперь при загрузке компа grub предлагает выбрать ос, но в списке одна только винда